# converting a list of lists to a dictionary where where the lists inside the list contain two strings

Tags: python

I have a list of lists where the lists inside the list contain two strings. I am trying to map them into a dictionary where the key is the first string in the list, and the value is the second string in the list.

ie.
[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]] into {a:b,c:d,e:f}

however I am encountering an error with my code:
"list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

```
idtoname = {}
for x in csv_data:
    idtoname[csv_data[x[0]]] = csv_data[x[1]]
```

where csv_data is the list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

you can use sequence unpacking to make the expression more readable:

```
csv_data = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
idtoname = {}
for a, b in csv_data:
    idtoname[a] = b
# idtoname = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
idtoname = {}
for x in csv_data:
    idtoname[x[0]] = x[1]
```

Inside the loop x is already an element of csv_data.

Answer (score 0):

Change line three to `idtoname[csv_data[x[0]]] = x[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `dict()` on the list of lists:

```
>>> x = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
>>> dict(x)
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```

Comment: I guess that the It seems to me that the expected answer must solve the problem in a general case and not only for the given example.